# Java Hash Table giving NullPointerException when checking if string is not null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashtable

I have a hash table that is implemented using a node array, where the node contains a string and a boolean to check if there was a string there before for when searching for an element after elements have been deleted. I am getting a nullpointerexception at a place that I don't understand how I possibly could, in this line:

```
while(T.getElement(place) != null)
```

This is my code to do the loop that is throwing the exception.

Get Element is here:

```
public String getElement(int index){
        if (index != lastProbed)
            probeCount++;
        lastProbed = index;
        return table[index].str;
}
```

And this is my node class:

```
class Node {

boolean hadStr;
String str;


public Node() {
    str = null;
    hadStr = false;
}

}
```

I don't understand how I could be getting a null pointer in a place where I am just checking if a string is null.

Comment: what happens if `table[index]` is null? then `return table[index].str;` will give you a NPE

Comment: That actually helps a lot, thank you! Is there a better way to solve this rather than making a for loop in the constructor to initialize every node in my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not

```
public String getElement(int index){
        if (index != lastProbed)
            probeCount++;
        lastProbed = index;
        if (table[index] != null) {
           return table[index].str;
        }
        return null;
}
```